# jQuery image dissapears in hover with fade

Tags: jquery, image, hover, fade

I have a series of thumbnails which I would like to have showing in the main image on rollover. I have got the functionality working using a hover, however although the fade in works nicely, as soon as I rollout, it fades out but then the main image loses it's src completely and dissapears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var originalimg = $('#imageMain img').attr('src');
    $(".thumb").hover(function(){
        var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#imageMain img').fadeIn("slow").attr('src', currentimg);
        },function(){
        $('#imageMain img').fadeOut('slow').attr('src', originalimg);
    });
});
```

Thanks guys.
I haven't included the HTML as I assume it's quotes straightforward what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

not `.attr('src', originalimg);` but `.src = originalimg;`

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var originalimg = $('#imageMain img').attr('src');
    $(".thumb").hover(function(){
        var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#imageMain img').fadeIn("slow").src = currentimg;
        },function(){
        $('#imageMain img').fadeOut('slow').src = originalimg;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just remove the image altogether and add a new image in place, as you can then fade it in at the same time for a better effect! I've written this off the top of my head so hopefully it works!

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  
                var originalimg = $('#imageMain img').attr('src');
                $(".thumb").hover(function(){
                    var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
                    $('#imageMain img').fadeIn("slow").attr('src', currentimg);
                    },function(){
                    $('#imageMain img').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                    $("#imageMain").append("<img src='"+originalimg+"'/>").hide().fadeIn("slow");
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for trying... on hover the fade now doesn't work, also when you mouse off, it sort of fades to white, then fades the original. I 'm a bit closer I think.